# How to get cordova android 3.5.1 for Phonegap 3.5 local android build?

Tags: phonegap-build

I am working with Phonegap 3.5.0-0.20.14 version which has cordova 3.5.0-0.2.4. But as per this post which says about security fixes in cordova 3.5.1,
http://phonegap.com/blog/2014/08/07/cordova-android-3_5_0-patched-with-security-fixes/

How can i get this cordova-android 3.5.1 for Phonegap local android builds ? I am new bee to Phonegap.

Regards,
Swapna

Answer (score 2):

cordova platform add android@3.5.1 --usenpm

http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2014/08/04/android-351.html

Comment: Thanks Ben. So this secutiry fix is only in the cordova templates becoz i did see any change in the Cordova binary. Only the tempaltes in user home dir i see 3.5.1 templates for android.

Comment: This might work for cordova, but what about phonegap CLI?  When I execute the command I get "[error] 'platform add android@3.5.1' is not a phonegap.js command. See 'phonegap.js help'".